# Override .dockerignore file when using ADD

Tags: docker, overriding, dockerignore, rocker

I have one `Rockerfile` that builds 4 images; I also have one central `.dockerignore` file. For one of the images I require assets that are blocked by the `.dockerignore` file -- is there a way when doing `ADD` or `COPY` to force add / ignore this list?

It'll be a lot easier to do this in one file as opposed to three separate...!

Answer (score 8):

In a simple way no.

The `.dockerignore` file is used to filter what will be used in the build **before** even reading the `Dockerfile`.

The `docker daemon` does not see your build folder, when the build starts, all the files in the context build folder are compressed (or just packed) and send to the daemon and only then it will read your `Dockerfile` to build the container with the files it received.

More content about `.dockerignore`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file

Comment: This is [Rocker](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker) which does it's builds differently to Docker, one feature they document is that there are no "build context" uploads.

Comment: I took the `Rockerfile` thing as a misspelling... my bad

Answer (score 3):

In a normal Docker build the `.dockerignore` file affects the "build context" that is packaged up and sent to the docker server at the beginning of the build. If the "build context" doesn't contain the files then you can't reference them, so this is how the files are excluded. They don't "exist" for the build.

Rocker [claims to run differently by not sending a build context](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker#v1-note) to the server. The [code looks like each `ADD`/`COPY` step is composed into a tar file that ignores the files](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker/blob/30ec46fe4f8310e27c20fcdd9b937a60f8cdb802/src/build/copy.go#L126). Also, the [`.dockerignore` is read once at startup and cached](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker/blob/30ec46fe4f8310e27c20fcdd9b937a60f8cdb802/main.go#L326-L333).

As Rocker is not sending the build context before each build, only filtering for each `ADD`/`COPY` command, there is hope. But due to the ignore data being read only once at startup you can't do anything funky like copying different `.dockerignore` files at different stages of the build though.

#### Use `MOUNT`

One option is to continue using the `.dockerignore` as is and use a [Rocker `MOUNT` command](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker#mount) to manually copy the ignored directories. Their last example in the mount section demonstrates:

```
FROM debian:jessie
ADD . /app                       # assets/ in .dockerignore
WORKDIR /app
MOUNT .:/context
RUN cp -r /context/assets /app   # include assets/
```

#### Change App Structure

The only other useful option I can think of is to split out your `ADD` or `COPY` into multiple commands so that you don't rely on the the `.dockerignore` to filter files to the other 3 images. This would probably require your `assets` directory to be stored outside of your application root.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is much appreciated. I'll take a look into mounting, it sounds like a neat solution to the problem. The assets directory is nearing 200mb, so having it in the `.dockerignore` is definitely a desire... :)

Comment: Rocker is now discontinued.